# How to run schema registry container for sasl plain kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I want to run the cp-schema-registry image on AWS ECS, so I am trying to get it to run on docker locally. I have a command like this:

```
docker run -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=schema-registry \
-e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS="1.kafka.address:9092,2.kafka.address:9092,3.kafka.address:9092" \
-e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_SECURITY_PROTOCOL=SASL_PLAINTEXT \
confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.5.3
```

(I have replaced the kafka urls).

My consumers/producers connect to the cluster with params:

```
["sasl.mechanism"] = "PLAIN"
["sasl.username"] = <username>
["sasl.password"] = <password>
```

Docs seem to indicate there is a file I can create with these parameters, but I don't know how to pass this into the docker run command. Can this be done?

Comment: You've mentioned SASL_SSL in that file, but your brokers are plaintext... Surely that's incorrect, but why do you think you need this file? (of course you can mount files with a volume or build your own container with it) I think you should be using specific schema registry config values because schema registry doesn't read any other property files than its own

Comment: I am unable to find config values that correspond with sasl.username and sasl.password. I will edit my question and remove SASL_SSL, I think that was a mistake.

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/authentication_sasl_plain.html#sr For example, `SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_SASL_MECHANISM` and `SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize I could pass jaas config like that. I am running it like this:
`docker run -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=schema-registry \
-e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS="1.kafka.broker:9092,2.kafka.broker:9092,3.kafka.broker:9092" \
-e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_SECURITY_PROTOCOL=SASL_PLAINTEXT \
-e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_SASL_MECHANISM=PLAIN \
-e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG='org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required
  username="my-username"
  password="my-password";' confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.5.3` but error

Comment: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JAAS config entry not terminated by semi-colon` despite the semicolon being there.

Comment: Hmm. I dont have any experience with doing this in Docker, but based on some examples on Github, maybe using Compose would help https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/gcp-pipeline/docker-compose-ccloud.yml#L19

Comment: I think the issue is the quoting in the terminal

Comment: Interesting. I changed it to be one line like `-e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG='org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="my-username" password="my-password";' ` and the semicolon issue is done, but now I see a WARN like " The configuration 'sasl.jaas.config' was supplied but isn't a known config." and then it fails to connect to brokers.

Comment: Ah, I got it to work. I did need to set `SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_SECURITY_PROTOCOL=SASL_SSL` and `SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_SASL_MECHANISM=PLAIN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to OneCricketeer for the help above with the `SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG` var. The command ended up like this (I added port 8081:8081 so I could test with curl):

```
docker run -p 8081:8081 -e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME=schema-registry \
-e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS="1.kafka.broker:9092,2.kafka.broker:9092,3.kafka.broker:9092" \
-e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_SECURITY_PROTOCOL=SASL_SSL \
-e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_SASL_MECHANISM=PLAIN \
-e SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_SASL_JAAS_CONFIG='org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username="user" password="pass";' confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:5.5.3
```

Then test with `curl localhost:8081/subjects` and get `[]` as a response.

Comment: Have you managed to create a docker-compose file? For some reason, the container does not take into account my environment variables. I have used the same names as you did.